# Why Java jni call on linux is slow as compare to windows?

Tags: java, linux, performance, java-native-interface

I am using java JNI having same code for windows and linux(Ubuntu) platform but facing a strange issue that the speed/performance of JNI call on linux(Ubuntu) is too slow as compare to windows. Following are the platform information
 - Window's-8 64-bit intel corei-7 machine with jdk 1.8.0, MinGW gcc 4.8.0
 - Ubuntu-15 64-bit intel corei-7 machine with jdk 1.8.0, Linux gcc 4.8.0
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is that the same native code compiled for the respective Platform/OS? Or did you do adaptations for each platform (and compiler-optimizations)?

Comment: When too slow, it probably is the back-and-forth wrapping of C code that behaves differently on Linux. You could measure the C part only, and look about the actual back and forth communication. Something influenced by InputStream.available or such.

Comment: @Fildor thank you for reply yeah the code is exactly same for both platform

Comment: @Joop Eggen when i run simple program of C the speed on both platform is same the issue is only in case on JNI

Comment: Then try a Hello-world JNI example app. It just maybe might be the .so loading or such. I do not know; I cannot imagine virus scanner, user rights or whatever could cause such a problem.

Comment: Without seeing code, I don't think we can answer this.

Comment: No one can possibly tell you why your code is slow in some situations without seeing the code.  If you don't post your code, you're not going to get an answer.